# Will any browser ignore cache control headers for URLs with a query string?

Tags: javascript, html, css, caching

I have a whole lot of css changes for my site. So I have used versioning to load the updated css files. But from some article I came to know that when some browsers like IE see a question mark they always hit the server to get the file but does not use the cache?

Is this true?

Comment: If the server gives a `304` it should load from _cache_

Comment: I believe that *some article* was wrong. Let's say that I wouldn't be surprised if IE of all browsers does something weird like that, but this is certainly not how it *should* behave at all.

Comment: @deceze: https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/caching , Check the last paragraph `Recomendation`, It says the same

Comment: That's only explicitly mentions *proxies*, not browsers.

Comment: @deceze: I am new to web development.Could  you please explain me what the difference between proxies and browsers.What exactly it says

Comment: The browser is the thing displaying the website, like Chrome or Firefox. The web server is the thing serving the website. A proxy is a thing which *may* sit in-between the two, maybe as part of a company network or CDN system or some such for various reasons. Proxies usually just forward any traffic along, but may also cache content to improve speed and reduce repeated downloads.

Answer (score 1):

It varies. The main concern is not IE, but rather proxy servers between you and the client.

Personally, I use links of the form `//example.com/t=12345/css/main.css`

That `t=12345` is the file's modification time, inserted by my "static resource management" class.

Then, a simple `.htaccess` rewrite rule strips that part out, leaving just `/css/main.css` as the target file.

From the browser's perspective, it's just a weirdly named folder, and it will cache according to the headers it receives. This will work for proxy servers too. Anything that can cache, will cache.